# Python library aiogram. How to add several inline buttons at once

Tags: python-3.x, button, telegram-bot, inline, aiogram

How to add several inline buttons at once, so as not to write a separate line of code for each button and at the same time to display these buttons three in each row.
I tried this code but i get this:
Code:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import csv

from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import filters, Text
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, WebAppInfo, KeyboardButtonPollType, \
    InlineKeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove

API_TOKEN = '5539016910:AAE0QLol57MMWA65-G0dxu-F69exdXlS-B4'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

def read_csv(file_name):
    file = open(file_name)
    file.readline()
    return csv.reader(file)


regions = {name: _id for _id, name in read_csv('regions.csv')}
districts = {_id: {name: reg_id} for _id, name, reg_id in read_csv('districts.csv')}


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def region(message: types.Message):
    url8 = 'https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/quick_start.html'
    rkm = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_wigth=3)
    l = list(regions.keys())
    for i in range(len(l)):
        rkm.row(InlineKeyboardButton(l[i], url=url8))
    await message.answer("Regions of Uzbekistan:", reply_markup=rkm)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIV16.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the name of the parameter passed to the `InlineKeyboardMarkup` constructor. You should also do `.add`, not `.row`.

```py
    rkm = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    l = list(regions.keys())
    for i in range(len(l)):
        rkm.add(InlineKeyboardButton(l[i], url=url8))
```

Comment: Don't forget to click the "☑️" so your question will help out others, too.